# Substracting adjacent two values in a list C#

Tags: c#

There is a list called cardReaderHistory . That contains some time records in ordered fashion as follows,

InTime1
 OutTime1
 InTime2
 OutTime2
 InTime3
 OutTime3
 InTime4
 OutTime4.....furthermore..

What I need is Calculate Working time by  (OutTime1 - Intime1) + (OutTime1 - Intime1).....
 double 
How could I do this in C#...????

```
 double hr = ((outTime1 - inTime1)+(OutTime2 - Intime2)+...);
```

Thank you..
Poor Beginner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can filter the input sequence based on the index, and then zip the two sequences:

```
var inTimes = source.Where((x, index) => index % 2 == 0);
var outTimes = source.Where((x, index) => index % 2 == 1);

var result = inTimes.Zip(outTimes, (inTime, outTime) => outTime - inTime).Sum();
```

If you don't need the intermediary values, you can also do this:

```
var result = source.Select((x, index) => (index % 2 == 0) ? -x : x).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your cardReaderHistory list is a list of doubles:

```
List<double> cardReaderHistory = new List<double>(); //fill it somewhere
double result;

for(int i = 0; i < cardReaderHistory.Count(); i++)
{
 if(i%2==0) //If it is equal
  result -= cardReaderHistory[i];
 else //its unequal 
  result += cardReaderHistory[i];
}
```

You just loop over your values and add or subtract based on if its even or not.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
 List<double> l = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
 double hr = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
 {
     hr += i%2 == 0 ? -l[i] : l[i];
 }
```

Comment: Ah looks like I was beaten to the punch. The above solutions are pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

It seems plausible that the list contains datetimes and not hours. Currently none of the other answers handles that. Here's my take.

```
var cardReaderHistory = new List<DateTime> {DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-120), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-100), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20), DateTime.Now};
var hours = cardReaderHistory.Split(2).Select(h => (h.Last() - h.First()).TotalHours).Sum();
```

`Split` is an extension method

```
static class ExtentionsMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, int size)
    {
        while (seq.Any())
        {
            yield return seq.Take(size);
            seq = seq.Skip(size);
        }
    }
}
```